# Access control configuration Logic Apps via ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to deploy the accessControl section of a Logic App via an ARM template ?
I used the LogicAppTemplateCreator from GitHub (https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator) to retrieve the ARM definition of the Logic and I tried to add the accessControl section but because it is not inside the definition of the Logic app itself, my ARM template is not valid.
Then, what is the best option to automatize the configuration of Logic Apps access controls?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, access control is part of the logic app resource definition, and can be included in the template. See the following for details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app

The relevant section you want included as part of your logic app resource template is below

```
{
    "name:" "myLogicAppWithAccessControl"
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"
    "properties": {
        "definition": { <your logic app definition> },
        "accessControl": {
            "triggers": {
                "allowedCallerIpAddresses": [
                    {
                        "addressRange": "192.168.12.0/23"
                    },
                    {
                        "addressRange": "2001:0db8::/64"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```